# Convert c# use of Service reference to vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, iis

I'm hoping that someone can help me convert this code from c# to vb.net.  I'm trying to use an IIS to publish subscribe info from a VB app to a c# app.  I need to use VB for one part of the app but need to use c# for the other part.  I know this isn't ideal but it's the position i'm in so would be great-full if someone could help.  I can convert the most of it but stuck with the first bit which I have little to no clue about. Not even sure it's possible as MSDN have removed VB example code and only show c# code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SeagateServiceClient
{
public class Client : PubSubService.ISampleContractCallback
{
    private PubSubService.SampleContractClient client;
    public void Subscribe()
    {
        try
        {
            InstanceContext site = new InstanceContext(null, new Client());
            client = new PubSubService.SampleContractClient(site);

            //create a unique callback address so multiple clients can run on one machine
            WSDualHttpBinding binding = (WSDualHttpBinding)client.Endpoint.Binding;
            string clientcallbackaddress = binding.ClientBaseAddress.AbsoluteUri;
            //string clientcallbackaddress = "http://localhost:9000/myClient/";
            clientcallbackaddress += Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            binding.ClientBaseAddress = new Uri(clientcallbackaddress);

            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = @"temp";
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "NN";
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "temp";

            //Subscribe.
            Console.WriteLine("Subscribing");
            client.Subscribe();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    public void UnSubscribe()
    {
        if(client != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unsubscribing");
                client.Unsubscribe();
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (client != null && (client.State.ToString() != "Closed" && client.State.ToString() != "Faulted"))
                    client.Close();
            }
        }

    }

    public void PushPriceChange(string item, double price, double change)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PriceChangePushed(item {0}, price {1}, change {2})", item, price.ToString("C"), change);
            client.PublishPriceChange("test", 22, 234);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    public void PriceChange(string item, double price, double change)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PriceChange(item {0}, price {1}, change {2})", item, price.ToString("C"), change);
    }
}
}
```

VB.net Attempt:

```
Imports System.Linq
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text
Imports System.ServiceModel

Public Module PublishData

Public Sub Test()
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is a test")
End Sub

Public client As PubSubService.SampleContractClient

Public Sub Subscribe()
    Try
        InstanceContext site = New InstanceContext(null, New Client())
        client = New PubSubService.SampleContractClient(site)

        'create a unique callback address so multiple clients can run on one machine
        WSDualHttpBinding binding = (WSDualHttpBinding)client.Endpoint.Binding
            String clientcallbackaddress = binding.ClientBaseAddress.AbsoluteUri
            'string clientcallbackaddress = "http://localhost:9000/myClient/"
        clientcallbackaddress += Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        binding.ClientBaseAddress = New Uri(clientcallbackaddress

        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = @"temp"
        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "NN"
        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "temp"

        'Subscribe.
        Console.WriteLine("Subscribing")
        client.Subscribe()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub UnSubscribe()
    If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(client)) Then
        Try
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Unsubscribing")
            client.Unsubscribe()
            client.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace)
        Finally
            If ((Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(client)) And (client.State.ToString() IsNot "Closed" And client.State.ToString() IsNot "Faulted")) Then
                client.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub PushPriceChange(item As String, price As Double, change As Double)
    Try
        Console.WriteLine("PriceChangePushed(item {0}, price {1}, change {2})", item, price.ToString("C"), change)
        client.PublishPriceChange("test", 22, 234)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
End Sub


Public Sub PriceChange(item As String, price As Double, change As Double)
    Console.WriteLine("PriceChange(item {0}, price {1}, change {2})", item, price.ToString("C"), change);
End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: there are a lot of online services that can convert c# to vb, and from c# to vb is more simple cause is strict typed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head (Obviously it is not tested)

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Namespace SeagateServiceClient
Public Class Client Implements PubSubService.ISampleContractCallback

Private client As PubSubService.SampleContractClient
Public Sub Subscribe()
Try
    Dim site As New InstanceContext(Nothing, New Client())
    client = New PubSubService.SampleContractClient(site)

    Dim binding As WSDualHttpBinding = DirectCast(client.Endpoint.Binding, WSDualHttpBinding)
    Dim clientcallbackaddress As String = binding.ClientBaseAddress.AbsoluteUri

    clientcallbackaddress += Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    binding.ClientBaseAddress = New Uri(clientcallbackaddress)

    client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "temp"
    client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "NN"
    client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "temp"


    Console.WriteLine("Subscribing")
    client.Subscribe()
Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace)
End Try
End Sub

Public Sub UnSubscribe()
    If client IsNot Nothing Then
    Try
        Console.WriteLine("Unsubscribing")
        client.Unsubscribe()
        client.Close()
    Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace)
Finally
        If client IsNot Nothing AndAlso (client.State.ToString() <> "Closed" AndAlso client.State.ToString() <> "Faulted") Then
                client.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End If
End Sub

Public Sub PushPriceChange(item As String, price As Double, change As Double)
Try
        Console.WriteLine("PriceChangePushed(item {0}, price {1}, change {2})", item, price.ToString("C"), change)
        client.PublishPriceChange("test", 22, 234)
Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace)
End Try
End Sub

Public Sub PriceChange(item As String, price As Double, change As Double)
            Console.WriteLine("PriceChange(item {0}, price {1}, change {2})", item, price.ToString("C"), change)
End Sub
End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Thank you, Couldn't have asked for more.